# Impossible to install libudev-dev on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04

```
sudo apt install libudev-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I couldn't find any solution. Some answers say "upgrade everything and it will work", but I have upgraded right now (2 hours ago) and the error remains. It says I have held broken packages, but `sudo apt-mark showhold` shows nothing (empty list).

I just need to install `libudev-dev`, any version. Suggestions, please?

```
apt policy libudev-dev && apt policy libudev1
libudev-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libudev1:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is my `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` - just one line, this is after following the suggestion to delete this file, run "Software & Updates" and tick all the checkboxes:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again. If it doesn't work please add output of `apt policy libudev-dev && apt policy libudev1` to your question. The versions look wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6: thanks for looking into it, I have added the policy output. I have run `apt update`, `apt upgrade` and rebooted at least 20 times in the last 4 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have disabled `jammy-updates` repository.

You did something wrong with the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

You can revert to the default one by deleting it and then enabling all repositories in Software & Updates.

You also need to enable all updates at the "Updates" tab.

The problem is that `jammy-updates` used to be enabled before and package versions do not match.

Comment: I did as you said, then ran `update && upgrade`, but the error message when installing `libudev-dev` didn't change. `apt policy` output also seems to be the same. Is reboot required after wiping `/etc/apt/sources.list`? I did not reboot.

Comment: I have 4 checkboxes ticked in "Software & Updates" (all except "Sources"), but only one line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, is that normal?

Comment: No, you don't need a reboot. Simply `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list`, then start software and & updates and click on all repos at the first tab, except source code. Then it should work

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/sources.list` to the question.

Comment: Done, question updated at the bottom.

Comment: you also need to change the Updates tab. Select all updates. You need to have `jammy-updates` in the file.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That did the trick. I didn't realize that setting exists.